# Inserting 0's into the middle of a string until certain length in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to add 0's into the middle of a string until a certain length.

e.g.

```
AB1
AB2
AB54
```

Would become:

```
AB0001
AB0002
AB0054
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Using `stringr::str_replace` extract the numbers from the string and use `sprintf` to add 0's as prefix.

```
stringr::str_replace(df$V1, '\\d+', function(m) sprintf('%04s', m))
#[1] "AB0001" "AB0002" "AB0054"
```

Another way to write the same logic with `str_pad` instead of `sprintf`.

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(df$V1, '\\d+', function(m) str_pad(m, 4, pad = '0'))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("AB1", "AB2", "AB54")), 
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 5):

For a base R approach, we can try using `strsplit` on each input using the regex pattern `(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])`, which will target the split between the letter and numbers potions.  Then, we can left pad the number with zeroes to a width of 4 and paste together the two portions.

```r
x <- c("AB1", "AB2", "AB54")
output <- sapply(x, function(x) {
    parts <- strsplit(x, "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
    paste0(parts[1], sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(parts[2])))
})
output

     AB1      AB2     AB54
"AB0001" "AB0002" "AB0054"
```